# Html form's action attribute

Tags: html

My html form is:

```
<form action='update/'>
   some code here ...
</form>
```

When the form is submitted at a url, `127.0.0.1/account/1`, it sends the request to `127.0.0.1/account/update`.

I want it to send the request to `127.0.0.1/account/1/update`.

(I am using Django)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve a relative path:

1. Take the base URL
2. Remove everything after the path
3. Remove everything after the last `/` in the path
4. Append the relative path

You seem to want it to skip step 3, but you can't can't change the way that works.

So your options:

- Change the current page's URL to `/account/1/`
- Change the `action`'s path to `1/update`
- Change the `action`'s  to an absolute path (`/account/1/update`)
- Write a JavaScript submit event handler that converts the `action` to an absolute path using your own rules.

I don't recommend the last option.